# Print pandas rows cells as string

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to print a data frame where each cell appears as a string:

**Dataset**

```
    a               b            c        
0 car        new york        queens  
1 bus        california      los angeles 
2 aircraft   illinois        chicago 
3 rocket     texas           houston  
4 subway     maine           augusta 
5 train      florida         miami
```

**Mon script:**

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    print(df["a"], "\n", testes["c"], "\n", testes["b"])
```

**My output:**

0 car

1 bus

2 aircraft

3 rocket

4 subway

5 train

Name: a, dtype: object

...

**Good output:**

```
car
queens 
new york

bus
los angeles
california

...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looping is slow, but possible if use `row` `Series`:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    print(row["a"], row["c"], row["b"], sep="\n")
```

Another idea is convert columns to numpy array:

```
for a, b, c in df[['a','b','c']].to_numpy():
    print(a, c, b, sep="\n")
```

Or `zip`:

```
for a, b, c in zip(df['a'],df['b'],df['c']):
    print(a, c, b, sep="\n")
```

Answer (score 2):

One way to achieve that is using apply:

```
df.apply(lambda row: print(f"{row['a']}\n{row['c']}\n{row['b']}\n"), axis = 1)
```